# Cross Platforming and Cross Languaging Sockets

Tags: python, swift, sockets, cross-platform

I am currently building a python application which uses sockets to communicate with other computers. I am almost finished with the backend (the frontend still looks atrocious), and I began thinking about expanding. Currently, my app is only intended to support Windows PC; however, I would like to expand to ios which would necessitate the use of Swift. I am writing this question to ask if python sockets can be shared across different types of devices (i.e. PC and iPhone) and different programming languages (i.e. Python and Swift). I am pretty sure that they can be shared across different types of devices, but I am unsure as to whether or not they can be shared with other programming languages. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to implement anything yourself?  StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to illustrate the specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with network "sockets" as that is simply one way, of many, to send data between processes. You are actually asking how to exchange data between processes that might be written in different languages. That is known via various acronyms such as "IPC" (interprocess communication).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A socket in Python provides the same abstraction as a socket in C, C++, Perl, ruby, Java ... . This means application written in various languages can all communicate using sockets with each other. What is different are WebSockets in Javascript in the browser though - these need another WebSockets implementation as the peer but these can also be found for various programming languages.

Comment: Thank you for your response!